# Choosing from a bag that contains 10 purple balls and 10 orange balls, how many must a man select to get at least 3 purple balls?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What are the steps to doing a problem like this? Do we first calculate the total number of balls in the bag?

Answer (score 2):

This is the pigeonhole principle. To guarantee the selection of $3$ purple balls, the number of balls chose must exceed the number of orange balls by $3$. That is, $10 + 3 = 13$ balls.